# Triggering uncheck doesn't work for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes which when get checked or unchecked cause the url to change through turbolinks so the page doesn't reload. I also have a "Clear all" link which uncheck all checkboxes.

```
$(document).on("click", "#all_filters", function() {
    $(".filterss input[type='checkbox'").prop("checked", false);
  });
```

The issue is it doesn't change the url of the page back even when I do this, so `triggerHandler` doesn't call the proper action to make it change, although it does uncheck the checkboxes:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#all_filters", function() {
   $(".filterss input[type='checkbox'").prop("checked", false).triggerHandler("change");
   // $(".filterss input[type='checkbox'").prop("checked", false).triggerHandler("click");
 });
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".filterss input[type='checkbox']")
```

You missed a bracket.
Try this if the bracket doesn't solve:

```
$(".filterss input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

Have a nice day friend! And if this didn't solve, I hope it helped you in some way.

Comment: actually, yes, but this is not the cause.

Comment: Thank you. So, let's try fix this. Let's continue investigating! ;)